# How to schedule jenkins job on AWS EC2 from jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-cli

I have created one EC2 instance in AWS.
Made necessary changes in the Jenkins->Manage Jenkins -> Configuration -> Cloud , to make access to that instance with the help of Amazon EC2 pLUGIN  :https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin

Now i wanted to run my jenkins jobs to run on EC2 when they got triggered periodically..

Please suggest me how to do that.

Comment: As per the documentation of the plugin, this will allow you to create a load-balancing cluster of Jenkins agents on EC2. Once that is done, it is upto the job/jenkins configuration to use these "agents" to run the job on.
You can "restrict" the job to use same "node".

Comment: You can also provide Labels to your EC2 node on Jenkins and also assign the relevant jobs with the same label.
So whenever the job is triggered, it will be assigned to the ec2 node